# get count from oData enabled web api Get function

Tags: odata, mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-web-api-odata, odatacontroller

i have an oData enabled classic REST web api controller with a Get function like

```
[EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<StoreCommand> Get()
    {
        return _storeCommandService.GetAllStoreCommands().AsQueryable();
    }
```

i need to understand how i can make a call to get only the count of records using some url

i tried

```
http://localhost:9910/api/storeCommandsrest?$count
```

but i get

Message: "The query parameter '$count' is not supported."

please note that i am using MongoDb that is returning IQueryable of collection.

Comment: Did you try with $count=true? Looks fine otherwise...

Comment: it has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **only the count**, try

```
http://localhost:9910/api/storeCommandsrest/$count
```

Comment: Thats what my question was, when i use $count i get "$count is not supported"